Errors using python-telegram-bot
I am having a small problem.
After initializing my raspberry pi4 (bookworm), the programs that used to work stop working and give me errors. How can I fix this?
Here is the code.
import logging
import subprocess
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext
from telegram import Bot
import socket
~~~
~~~
def main() -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    ip_address = get_ip_address()
    send_message(ip_address)
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("stop", stop))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I am getting below error after executing the script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/server/my_app/stream.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/server/my_app/stream.py", line 44, in main
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'


Does this answer your question? TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
